# Unable to scan for beacons

Tags: android, beacon, android-ibeacon

I have been trying to scan for beacons, but I'm not able to. I tried all the StackOverflow questions but I haven't found an answer.

Below is my code:

**MAINACTIVITY:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements BeaconConsumer {

protected static final String TAG = "MonitoringActivity";
private BeaconManager beaconManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
     beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().
            setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=beac,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25"));
    beaconManager.bind(this);}

 @Override
public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {
    beaconManager.addMonitorNotifier(new MonitorNotifier() {
        @Override
        public void didEnterRegion(Region region) {
            Log.i(TAG, "I just saw an beacon for the first time!");
        }

        @Override
        public void didExitRegion(Region region) {
            Log.i(TAG, "I no longer see an beacon");
        }

        @Override
        public void didDetermineStateForRegion(int state, Region region) {
            Log.i(TAG, "I have just switched from seeing/not seeing beacons: "+state);
        }
    });

    try {
        beaconManager.startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(new Region("myMonitoringUniqueId", Identifier.parse(null, null, null));
    } catch (RemoteException e) {    }
}
```

**MANIFEST**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
```

**gradle.properties**

```
manifestmerger.enabled=true
```

**logcat**

```
06-19 20:03:37.403 7459-7459/com.example.beaconscanner D/BeaconParser: Parsing beacon layout: m:2-3=beac,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25

06-19 20:03:37.796 7459-7459/com.example.beaconscanner I/MonitoringActivity: I have just switched from seeing/not seeing beacons: 0

06-19 20:03:37.933 7459-7729/com.example.beaconscanner D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
06-19 20:03:37.938 7459-7471/com.example.beaconscanner D/BluetoothLeScanner: onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=12

06-19 20:03:39.038 7459-7729/com.example.beaconscanner D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
06-19 20:03:39.040 7459-7729/com.example.beaconscanner D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
06-19 20:03:39.044 7459-7470/com.example.beaconscanner D/BluetoothLeScanner: onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=12
```

I have added permissions for location and Bluetooth according to Android SDK greater than 23

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears from your debug lines that Android is detecting bluetooth devices, which suggests that bluetooth is on and your app has permission to scan.

A few things to check:

1. Make sure your BeaconLayout is correct.  "m:2-3=beac,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25" is for AltBeacon.  If your beacon is transmitting a different format (e.g. iBeacon or Eddystone) you will need a different layout.  A good reference is here:  https://beaconlayout.wordpress.com/
2. Make sure your device actually is sending out a valid beacon signal.  I'd suggest my [Locate app for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.radiusnetworks.locate&hl=en), as it automatically detects all beacons advertising iBeacon, AltBeacon and Eddystone formats.

Comment: It works the solution was changing the Beaconlayout to `m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24`